# Probability of a grid with row and column

Tags: probability

Put the nine different numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ at random in nine different places in a $3×3$ grid. What is the probability that each row sum and column sum is odd?

Comment: I don't even understand how to begin...

Comment: Begin by finding out whether it's even possible to meet these conditions. Then try to see if you can find how to count the number of ways to meet them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

1. Prove that one row has to be full of odd numbers, and one column has to be full of odd numbers, and except that row and that column all numbers are even.
2. Compute the number of ways to choose which row and which column are going to be the odd ones.
3. Compute the number of ways to fill the chosen row/column with the odd numbers and the remaining placeholders with even numbers.
4. Do the relevant multiplications and divide by the total number of ways to fill the grid arbitrarily.

Comment: Would it be possible for you guys to tell me what the correct answer is? I believe it is 1/14 but am not sure. It would be also really helpful if you could solve the problem explaining your steps. Thanks!

Comment: @SamRalph this is not a site where people give answers or do your homework from scratch, you have enough hints to at least try. If you don't get to the end, upload your work and people will see where you are stuck.

Comment: We have four even numbers and we can't place in a row (column) just an even number or three even numbers. So we must have on every rows (columns) none or two even numbers. If we have an even number on a certain row, then we must have another one on the same line and so we got two columns with an even number and so we must have one more even number on these columns.

Comment: We conclude that the numbers $2,4,6,8$ must be the corners of a rectangular i.e. the squares from the intersections of two rows and two columns.
We can choose these two rows in $3$ ways and the columns in $3$ ways.
For every choice we can plug the numbers $2,4,6,8$ randomly and this can be done in $4!=24$ ways. Then we just have to fill the rest of squares with the numbers $1,3,5,7,9$ randomly and we can do this in $5!=120$ ways.
So the number of favorable situations is $9 \cdot 24 \cdot 120.$
Hence the probability is $\frac{9 \cdot 4! \cdot 5!}{9!}=\frac{1}{14}.$

Comment: Is my work correct?

Comment: @SamRalph All good!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Exactly one row must be all odds and exactly one column must be all odds. That leaves the remaining $4$ slots to be even numbers. How many combinations are there?

**Hint 2:** See Mostafa Ayaz's diagram. How many ways can you place the two orange lines? How many ways can you arrange the numbers within those orange lines? How many ways can you arrange the remaining four blues.?

Comment: Could you help me out by elaborating the hint and maybe solving the problem. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Do you have enough information now to attempt a calculation? I hesitate to do it for you if you haven't tried.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 even numbers and 5 odd numbers so the only valid cases are

[image]

each containing $5!\times 4!$ different cases. So we have $5\times 5!\times 4!=14400$ different cases in total.

Comment: How did you make this graphic?

Comment: I used paint :)

Comment: You are missing $4$ configurations.

Comment: So how is it? Would you give me a sketch?

Comment: Top row and rightmost column and similarly for the other $3$. I didn't catch that initially.

Comment: I don't understand. Is there anything wrong with my answer?